# Jane and Mark's and my house

Tags: grammar

When an object belongs to three people, how do you write the possessive noun forms? If a house belongs to Jane, Mark, and myself, do I say 'Jane and Mark's and my house?'

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you are talking about ownership between multiple people, the possessive is indicated for each person if they each own something individually:

> Jane's and Mark's and Taylor's houses.

Here, they each own a house of their own.

But if something is owned by all of them collectively, then you apply the possessive only to the final person in the list:

> Jane and Mark and Taylor's house.

Here, it's a single house of which they share joint ownership.

Of course, things can get tricky when trying to express certain things, and you may need to rewrite the sentence in order to avoid confusion.

For example, what if Jane and Mark jointly own a house, while Taylor owns a different one?

> Jane and Mark's and Taylor's houses.

This would be *technically* correct, but it leads to confusion. It would be clearer written as:

> Jane and Mark's house and Taylor's house.

This makes it obvious who owns what. (Although the meaning is now clear, it still sounds a bit awkward and could perhaps be further rewritten.)

In your example sentence, however, you've used a pronoun. When you use pronouns it makes things even more difficult.

> Mark and her house.
>   Mark's and her houses.

Here, what I'm trying to express is either the house collectively owned by Mark and Jane or the houses owned by each. Neither works well.

> His and her houses.

This is also ambiguous. It's not even clear if the pronouns are being used as possessive adjectives; I could be referring to houses that are meant to be used by two genders. (In other words, not a possessive at all but a simple noun phrase.)

Where does that leave your example sentence? Despite whatever technically correct rule there is, you will want to rephrase it.

Try:

> The house that belongs to Jane, Mark, and me.

Of course, most people in conversation will understand who the owners are anyway and specifying them wouldn't be needed:

> It's our house.
>   It belongs to all of us.

Answer (score 1):

You can, although it might be better to use the possessive for each of the owners:

> It is **Jane's** and **Mark's** and **my** house.

However, this is still relatively unclear.  In such situations, I would choose to be a little more explicit:

> The house belongs to **all three of us** -- Jane and Mark and me.

or

> The house is **all three of ours** -- Jane's and Mark's and mine.

Comment: If Jane and Mark own, jointly, a half share of a house, and I own the other, I could write "Jane and Mark's and my house".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I don't think that sentence by itself clearly defines the distribution of ownership.  We still don't know who owns how much of the house.  Again, if it's important be explicit:  *"Jane and Mark own half the house, and I the other half"*